# PHP - aceitar break lines

Tags: php

Eu fiz um `preg_match` onde aceita diversos caracteres.
De momento eu queria que aceita-se **BREAK LINE** também, quando uma pessoa aperta **ENTER** para ir linha abaixo.

Como faço?

Exemplo do que fiz:

```
!preg_match('#^[a-z0-9\-+, .\#*()\\/]+$#i', $ads_description
```

Answer (score 2):

Provavelmente seria `\n` o que deseja, assim:

```
preg_match('#^[a-z0-9\-+, .\#*()\\/\n]+$#i', $ads_description)
```

Claro que pode usar o `\s` que vai equivaler ao `\n`, ao espaço e ao tab (`\t`), assim resumiria a expressão regular para:

```
preg_match('#^[a-z0-9\-+,.\#*()\\/\s]+$#i', $ads_description)
```

Exemplo no IDEONE: https://ideone.com/wMIwLL

Só pra constar, `a-z` não aceita acentos, só aceita a,e,i,o,u,b,c,d..., letras como `ã`, `õ`, etc precisam ser especificadas, então deve ficar assim (para aceitar a letra a com acentos, um exemplo curto apenas para entender):

```
preg_match('#^[a-z0-9ãáà\-+,.\#*()\\/\s]+$#i', $ads_description)
```

Mas é possivel simplificar, usando `\p{L}` (provavelmente os dados estão em utf-8 então use o modificador `u`), assim:

```
<?php

$ads_description = '250.000km, Revisão feita.
Inspeccionado ate Julho 2018.
Novo kit embreagem, travoes, cardans. Encontra-se em muito bom estado.';

if (!preg_match('#^[\p{L}0-9\-+,.\#*()\\/\s]+$#iu', $ads_description)) {
    echo 'Erro';
} else {
    echo 'Certo';
}
```

---

<s>Se underline/underscore `_` também puder ser aceito, então você poderia resumir o a-z0-9 e _ com metacaractere `\w` (o a-z é case insensitive, o que dispensaria o modificador `i` após o `#`), então isto:</s>

```
preg_match('#^[\w\-+,.\#*()\\/\s]+$#', $ads_description)
```

Seria o mesmo que:

```
preg_match('#^[a-z0-9\-+,.\#*()\\/\s]+$#i', $ads_description)
```

Comment: eu inseri exatamente esse que me enviou, mas ele da-.me um erro quando eu insiro esta mensagem "250.000km, Revisão feita. Inspeccionado ate Julho 2018. Novo kit embreagem, travoes, cardans. Encontra-se em muito bom estado.", será que introduzi algum caracter invalido?

Comment: visto que eu estou a usar if(!preg_match......)

Comment: @Rufus1090 o `!` faz a negação, a sua intenção é qual? Que "entre" na  IF quando tiver né? Então tem que tirar o `!`, agora se a intenção é que não entre na IF então esta certo, por favor se ainda falhar cria um exemplo no https://ideone.com **que funcione** e me manda para ver porque não entra na IF.

Comment: a intenção é que apenas aceite esses caracteres. Por isso o uso do !

Comment: por exemplo, se nao tiver esses caracteres, ele mostra mensagem.

Comment: exemplo:                     if(!preg_match('#^[\w\-+,.\#*()\\/\s]+$#', $ads_description)) {

   $errors[] = "

Comment: @Rufus1090 posta um exemplo no IDEONE. Aqui parece esta normal.

Comment: Sim a intenção e essa mesmo, "SE O CAMPO TEXTARES CONTER OUTROS CARACTERES A NAO SER ESSES, ELE DA ERRO"

Comment: eu introduzi esta frase e ele acusa de erro. "250.000km, Revisão feita. Inspeccionado ate Julho 2018. Novo kit embreagem, travoes, cardans. Encontra-se em muito bom estado."

Comment: @Rufus1090 não adianta DIGITAR TUDO EM MAIÚSCULO,  o problema é que você não postou o código integral e eu não posso ler mentes, vamos para o que interessa, veja aqui funciona https://ideone.com/DKsj92 --- Se não esta funciona é devido a outro caractere que não tem nada haver com as quebras de linha, já falei cria um exemplo do erro no IDEONE e me manda: https://ideone.com se não será impossivel te ajudar

Comment: esta aqui https://ideone.com/7p2YZv

Comment: @Rufus1090 isso aí não é um exemplo funcional do problema, é só um pedaço de código colado que nem executa, eu pedi pra criar um exemplo funciona do problema, ou seja um exemplo resumido com a parte que interessa e que realmente funcione. Tudo bem deixa pra lá, eu acho que já achei de qualquer forma o problema e estou editando a resposta. Aguarde alguns minutos

Comment: @Rufus1090 pronto, editei a resposta.

Comment: oK.. Ja entendi o erro, quando eu Preciono ENTER(linha abaixo), ele simplesmente ativa o erro.. por isso é que não deixa passar.. o \s nao resulta de todo... nem o \n

Comment: ok, existe alguma maneira de aceitar todos os caracters do tipo ()-*$%--- ?

Comment: @Rufus1090 posta teu script todo pra eu testar por favor, manda no http://pastebin.com e me manda o link aqui

Comment: Uma pergunta, e se eu apenas quisesse que o utilizador não pudesse por "<>, «», #, |, ? como faria?

Comment: @Rufus1090 assim: `if (preg_match('#[<>«»|?]#', $ads_description)) { echo 'Não pode "<>, «», #, |, ?"'; } else { echo 'Funcionou'; }`